# Problem loading a pdf file and rendering it in screen

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

Im triying to load a pdf file and render it in screen with the following code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pdf_viewer_plugin/pdf_viewer_plugin.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:developer';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  FileLoad createState() => FileLoad();
}

class FileLoad extends State<MyApp> {
  String _filePath = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test PDF',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue,),
      home:
        Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            items: const [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: "Home"),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.folder), label: "Load File")
            ],
            onTap: (int index) async {
              var go = 1;
              if (index == 1) {
                var status = await Permission.storage.status;
                if (status != PermissionStatus.granted) {
                  var result = await Permission.storage.request();
                  if (result != PermissionStatus.granted) {
                    go = 0;
                  }
                }
                if (go == 1) {
                  FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();
                  if (result != null) {
                    File file = File(result.files.single.path!);
                    setState(() {
                      _filePath = file.path;
                      log('_filePath: $_filePath');
                    });
                  }
                }
              }
            },
          ),
          body:
            PdfView(path: _filePath, gestureNavigationEnabled: true,)
        )
    );
  }
```

I can see the log with the correct filepath selected in the explorer, but nothing is rendered in the screen. What is wrong with the code?

Any error is triggered in the console.

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like that the PdfView itself doesn't load the newest path even with a setState(). I had this problem with other PDF-Viewer plugins.

I solved it by wrapping the PDFView into a if statement and while there is no path loaded some sort of loading Widget is displayed.

Like so:

```
String? _filePath;

 body:
       _filePath != null ? PdfView(path: _filePath, gestureNavigationEnabled: true,): Text("loading")
```